# listview Textview settext doesn't work with looping?

Tags: android, listview

```
listViewD.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

                            final CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

                            if (edit)
                            {

                                Integer tempoid = tinydb.getInt("tempoid");
                                if (tempoid>0)
                                {
                                    tempoid1=tinydb.getListBoolean(""+tempoid);
                                    String tempoooo = tempoid1.toString();
                                    int calories3 = 0;
                                    int i;
                                    for (i = 0; i < foodListD.size(); i++)
                                    {
                                        View view1 = View.inflate(context, R.layout.textblack1,null);
                                        adapter.getView(i, view1, parent);
                                        CheckBox checkbox1 = (CheckBox) view1.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                                        TextView text = (TextView) view1.findViewById(R.id.calories);

                                        String tempoid2= String.valueOf(tempoid1.get(i));

                                        String calories1 = text.getText().toString();
                                        Integer calories2 = Integer.valueOf(calories1);

                                        if (tempoid1.get(i))
                                        {
                                            checkbox1.setChecked(tempoid1.get(i));
                                            text.setText("");


                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

that is part of my code. I'm just wondering why does **text.setText("")** seems doesn't execute. I've tried to search and based on what I've searched, I need to use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() or invalidateViews() but it doesn't work. By the way, that code can retrieve the value of each textview by position in listview so I'm very sure that it works. The thing is it doesn't work with setText. What is wrong with my code?

edit: by the way, the "tinydb" part of my code is just simplified shared prefs from github.

Comment: You're updating the `AdapterView` the wrong way.  `AdapterView` children are populating from the model in Adapter. Do not change the View externally. Instead, change the model which you use in `getView()` of the Adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: How sir? Can you please show some line of codes. Sorry sir Im newbie.